# Page template is missing fields or is invalid when I updating the template

Tags: custom-field, pages, page-template, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to update a page template, and when I do something strange happens. Let me explain..

I have a template "Hat Size Guide" where the code file is `/themes/my-theme/pages/page-hat-size-guide.php`

I am trying to update that php file to include a hyperlink, and when I do the pages that had this template set no longer have this template set: I go to edit a page that uses this template and the Template is automatically set to "Default". Also when I try to set the template back to "Hat Size Guide", all of a sudden all my custom fields for this template are gone. Now when I restore the php file back to what is was, everything is restored to what it was.

I have even tried to just update the php file with a simple

`<div id="testingdiv">testing</div>`

and I get the same results. This is driving me mad! Does anyone know why this is happening?

Template file: [page-hat-size-guide.php](https://app.box.com/s/n3ai2ruznpni2dh3c4eet91w0ug4svn8)

Comment: Check the top of the file, in the comment section and make sure it follows `Template Name: Hat Size Guide` (in comments of course)

Comment: @bynicolas It does indeed

Comment: could you share your template code, there must be something conflicting elsewhere within that file!

Comment: @bynicolas For sure, I added a link to the file. The only change I've made to the file is the `awesomediv` @ line 72.

Comment: What app are you using to edit the file?  Could be an encoding or file type problem?  Sounds very strange.  If the "Template Name" value does not change, WP should use the current version of the file.  No need to re-assign it to pages that were using it before the edit.   What template DOES get assigned when the original is removed from the page?  Perhaps there is a clue in that behavior.

Comment: @jdm2112 is right, if your `Template Name` stays the same, WP will keep using that template for all pages using, it.  Maybe the app your are using is indeed causing issues.  Could you try to edit the same file **within** WP file editor in **Appearance->Editor** to see if you get the same behaviour

Comment: @jdm2112 I use PhpStorm, and am editing a direct copy of the original file. When I update the file, I go to edit the page and it no longer has the Template set as "Hat Size Guide", and the Template dropdown is set at "Default". Then when I set the dropdown to "Hat Size Guide", none of the custom fields that are normally there for this template show up; it is blank. I do not save the page; I just back out, and then I restore the template code file, go back to edit the page again and now the Template is properly set at "Hat Size Guide", and all fields are there again to edit.

Comment: Okay, so first of all thanks a lot for your guys' help. I think we're narrowing this down. I'm using FTP Rush and FTP'ing the file from the Linux web server to my Windows, modifying it and FTP'ing it back. Now all I did was FTP the file over to my local, make a backup on the web server, and FTP the file back over **without making any changes** and it is still having the same effect! That must mean there is an issue with FTP the file over from a Windows environment

Comment: @bynicolas Wow, I narrowed this even further to making a simple copy of the file on the linux web server breaks it. I don't even transfer it out or do anything to it, just a simple `cp page-hat-size-guide.php page-hat-size-guide_bu.php` and using the copied file causes it to break.

Comment: I'm sorry Nick but I have no idea what's causing that to fail.  I would recommend contacting your web host support folks and explain the problems.  They should be able to test and troubleshoot this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any white space below your code. You might have a "Japanese" white space Character. Anything else I can think of? I need 50 rep points to comment on this topic. Make sure to use unicode File transfers from Windows.

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned in comments above but I'll note here for you as well. Even just copying the file within the linux web server causes it to break. On the web server, I just simply `cp page-hat-size-guide.php page-hat-size-guide_bu.php` and use the copied file and it breaks it... Is that weird or what?